# How to change http to https in Prestashop 1.6 add cart

Tags: .htaccess, ssl, cart, prestashop-1.6

I enabled SSL on my Prestashop 1.6:

```
Preferences > General > Enable SSL
Preferences > General > Enable SSL on all pages
```

In .htaccess I used a following code:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

before

```
# ~~start~~ Do not remove this comment, Prestashop will keep automatically the code outside this comment when .htaccess will be generated again
```

Everything looks fine but in view page source of website still I see:

```
<a class="button ajax_add_to_cart_button btn btn-default" href="http://www.myeshop.com/cart?add=1&amp;id_product=9&amp;token=2db68311c3192a52b4eca5bc1b2c218f" rel="nofollow" title="Add to cart" data-id-product="9"> <span>Add to cart</span> </a>
```

A href link in *Add to cart* button directs to http instead https.
Can you help me please?
Regards
Jan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should look at the smarty template concerned and seeing if classes or controllers are not overridden.

at least you can correct it, with Javascript with something like :

```
$(document).ready(function()
{

   $('.ajax_add_to_cart_button').each(function() {
                var href = $(this).attr('href');
                href = href.replace('http:', 'https:');
                $(this).attr('href', href);
        });

 });
```

But it's only for test mode not in production due to security !!!
please read this thread :
[Change all occurrences of "http" to "https" on a wordpress page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6053661/change-all-occurrences-of-http-to-https-on-a-wordpress-page)

Comment: Thanks Melvita for your quick response. I put your source code into `themes/my_theme/js/modules/blockcart/ajax-cart.js`. When I use _Inspect_ in my Google Chrome I see https in _Add to cart_ button what is ok. But if I show all webpage source code I still see http instead https :(

Comment: yes, as i told you it 's a trick to let you find better solution. Javascript is not the best answer for your problem. the protocol needs to be ok from PHP then in smarty ll be https.  if you see source with http it can happen when you see source before Js is executed. but once again you need to correct it without Js, i m sorry but without source and code it s difficult to give more advice, hope you find a solution.cheers